# Angular 2 select text on specific input

Tags: angular

With jQuery, we would select all contents of a specific input on-submit this way:

```
<form id="target">
  <input id="input-1" type="text" value="some value" />
<form>
```

```
$("#target").submit((event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#input-1").select();
});
```

How do we accomplish this with Angular 2?

Comment: Did you got it?

Answer (score 76):

You can easily do it in the template like this:

```
<input type="text" (click)="$event.target.select()" />
```

or add a local variable to your element and reference that instead:

```
<input type="text" #myInput (click)="myInput.select()" />
```

The benefit of the second approach is that by setting a local variable name to your element, other elements can reference that variable as well.

Comment: Thank you Fredrick for this answer! We were fiddling with the focus event and running into issues. This saved us a lot of headache. And: "The benefit of the second approach is that by setting a local variable name to your element, other elements can reference that variable as well." Especially if you're using a third party control that wraps around the input so you have to handle the click event at the wrapper element level. Thanks so much!

Comment: As simple as possible!

Comment: Property 'select' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)

Comment: Yep, so you need to use the second option. That avoids the error.

Comment: note that `select()` does not work when input is `disabled`.

Answer (score 14):

I figured out a way without using an event listener...

```
<form id="target">
  <input id="input-1" #input-1 type="text" value="some value" />
<form>
```

component.ts

```
@ViewChild('input-1') inputOne: ElementRef;

selectInput() {
  const inputElem = <HTMLInputElement>this.inputOne.nativeElement;
  inputElem.select();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Btw, there is no need for the const, you can just do it in one line: <HTMLInputElement>this.inputOne.nativeElement.select();

Comment: This is awesome, and somewhat hard to find if you're not searching for the right thing. Fantastic find!

Comment: Is select() is deprecated ?

Comment: Great, but you may need to use setTimeout in order for the input to initialize first if you're doing this right after initializing component.

Answer (score 11):

A better idea for focus events is to use the focus event rather than the click event.

```
<input type="text" (focus)="$event.target.select()" />
```

To focus from inside your component logic you will need to add a few more things

1. Add a local variable name

```
<input type="text" #myInput (focus)="$event.target.select()" />
```

2. Use `ViewChild` to access your DOM element

```
@ViewChild("#myInput") myInputField: ElementRef;
editMyInputField(): void {
  this.myInputField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

To trigger the selection programmatically from outside the component you will need to use `@Input`. Something along the lines of:

```
@Input() set myInputFocus() {
  this.editMyInputField();
}
```

All this should still be working with Angular 8. I did not test any of this on Angular 2 or 4.

It would get a bit more complicated if you're using dynamic inputs. For such cases, I have used a form as the parent reference rather than declaring many local variables in the component.

Comment: This helps also accessibility if you tab to the input using keyboard navigation

Comment: It seems there's an issue with type here for content editable text. This is exactly what I tried, hmm.

Answer (score 7):

You can create directive like below and use it where you need:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelectOnFocus]'
})

export class SelectOnFocusDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('focus', null) onFocus() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.select();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mat-input, you can try **onfocus="this.select()"**

```html
<input matInput onfocus="this.select()">
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on @NobodySomewhere answer (thank you):
Same solution in a slightly different context of an input linked to a material autocomplete (documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)

```
      <input id="driver"
         type="text"
         placeholder="Search for a Driver"
         onfocus="this.select()"
         (ngModelChange)="setDriver($event)"
         [formControl]="driverAutoComplete"
         [matAutocomplete]="autoDriver">
  <mat-autocomplete #autoDriver="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let driver of filteredDrivers | async" [value]="driver">
      {{driver.fullname}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```